# Evaluate a Recurrence Relation

Tags: c

A recurrence relation T is defined on n >= 0 and is given as T(n) = T(n-1) + 2*n with the base case T(0) = 1.

You will be given one integer k and you have to write a program to find out T(k).

The program must implement T( ) recursively.

Here is my Code :

```
 include<stdio.h>  
 long long T(int input)  
 {  
 if(input == 0)  
 return 1;  

 return 2*input + T(input-1);  
}  
 int main()  
{  
 /*write your code here*/  
 int k;  
  scanf("%d",&k);  
 printf("%lli",T(k));  
 return 0;    
}
```

Here is the Error i got

```
   Program:1:9: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '<' token
   Program:In function 'main':
   Program:13:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'scanf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   Program:13:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'scanf' [enabled by           default]
   Program:14:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   Program:14:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by   default]
   Program:14:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'T' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   Program:14:4: warning: format '%lli' expects argument of type 'long long int', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]
```

How can i achieve the following Expected Results ?

```
Sample Test Cases

               Input    Output
Test Case 1     1           3
Test Case 2     2           7
Test Case 3     3          13
```

Comment: you should write #include<stdio.h>

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the square/hash/sharp `#` symbol behind the `include` on top.

Warnings indicate that `scanf` is not defined. Definition for that is given in `stdio.h` which you have failed to include.

Otherwise, your recursion function is pretty much alright.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. Change

```
include<stdio.h>
```

to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```